# ERROR:cannot dereference end list iterator

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I filled the list with the values. I am trying to use them again one by one.

I have tried `while (!config.empty())` and erased the front() after using it. still not getting where it is gone wrong.

```
std::list<Object*> config;
```

Filled config (after `config.push_back()`):

```
config[0]:
int testnumber = 1;
string testname = "Test1"

config[1]:
int testnumber = 2;
string testname = "Test2";

config[2];
int testnumber = 3;
string testname = "Test3";
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Logic* pLogic;
Object* pObject = config.front(); // config[0]

if (pObject) // while(!config.empty()) -- tried here 
{
    // do something
    pLogic = new Logic(pObject);
    config.pop_front();
}
```

**LOGIC:**

```
Object* m_pObject;

Logic::Logic(Object* pObject)
    :m_pObject(pObject)
 {}

  // Accessed config in other functions with m_pObject
```

Code works fine and getting the output. However in the end getting 
`ERROR: Debug assertion failed
Expression:cannot dereference end list iterator`

Comment: You can't call `front()` on an empty list.  Is `config` empty?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm No. because I have tried while(NOT empty())

Comment: Please show us the code with the `empty()` call you tried, i.e. [mcve]. Currently, your code presents a list that is always empty and no elements are inserted.

Comment: @JohnRees can you show us the `// do something` part? The problem is most likely there..

Comment: @KorelK I have added // do something part, can you please check it. Thank you

Comment: This is not an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `while` loop (`while (pObject)`) you are not updating (at least in your posted code) the pointer 'pObject', so it always points to the same old object that were at the beginning in the top of the list. This issue makes your loop infinity loop, so it will work as long as there are more objects inside your list to pop. in the itteration that make your program crash, it tries to pop an element from an empty list, and this is an UB.

To fix this issue, all you have to do is:

```
pObject = config.front()
```

after the line:

```
config.pop_front();
```

Comment: Check for emptiness first otherwise you're back where you started to some degree

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where to use the condition.

This is how it looks,

```
Logic* pLogic;
if(!config.empty())
{
    Object* pObject = config.front(); // config[0]
    if (pObject)  
    {
         // do something
         pLogic = new Logic(pObject);
     }
     config.pop_front();
 }
```